# Docker-compose containers not talking to each other in osx land

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

Have been having an issue with my setup in docker-compose on osx where the containers can't talk to each other on there own docker network either set explicitly or just in the default config. Now I'm no docker expert but from all the readings I've done sounds like this should be working out of the box.

Anyway please have a look at my config and let me know if Ive missing something really dumb. (Which I so hope as I need to move on the next task.)

```
version: "3"

services:
  ui-app:
    build: ./src/ui    
    env_file:
      - "./envs/ui-app.env"
    ports:
      - "3400:3400"
    networks:
      - local_dev_network
    links:
      - api-gateway

  api-gateway:
    build: ./src/api-gateway
    depends_on:
      - redis
    env_file:
      - "./envs/api-gateway.env"
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
    networks:
      - local_dev_network
    links:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - local_dev_network

  debug:
    build: ./src/debug
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    depends_on:
      - ui-app
      - redis
    networks:
      - local_dev_network
    links:
      - redis

networks:
  local_dev_network:
```

Comment: the `local_dev_network` must be indented. Also, how are you trying to access the other services from one service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're using *links* and also *user network bridges*.

Links are being deprecated to connect containers in order to use networks.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

So,

1. Let me recommend you remove `links`, because you've already create `local_dev_network`.
2. Although default `network_mode` is `bridge`, I would also specify it, because `network_mode: host` is not compatible with links. This is not needed in your case if you remove links but is a good practice.
3. If you don't want to move links, note that you're defining a network but you're not connecting all with all, despite of bridge definition. That's why you haven't defined several entries in `links:` section.

Definitively, you have two options:

- *links option*: remove `networks:` section and specify in links all containers. A linked to B, C, D; B linked to A, C, D... and not A linked with B, B linked with C.
- *networks option (recommended):*: remove `links:` section in your compose.

```
version: "3"

    services:
      ui-app:
        build: ./src/ui    
        env_file:
          - "./envs/ui-app.env"
        ports:
          - "3400:3400"
        networks:
          - local_dev_network

      api-gateway:
        build: ./src/api-gateway
        depends_on:
          - redis
        env_file:
          - "./envs/api-gateway.env"
        ports:
          - "5050:5050"
        networks:
          - local_dev_network

      redis:
        image: redis:alpine
        ports:
          - "6379:6379"
        networks:
          - local_dev_network

      debug:
        build: ./src/debug
        ports:
          - "5001:5001"
        depends_on:
          - ui-app
          - redis
        networks:
          - local_dev_network

    networks:
      local_dev_network:
```

If nothing of this works for you, maybe try with `network_mode: host`, also of course removing `links` section

Comment: Hey thanks for this @mulg0r, have just given your config a try and am still getting issues with the api-gateway connecting to the redis servers ```blockbid-api-gateway_1  | Error: Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379```

Comment: If redis needs to connect host interface `localhost`, add `network_mode: host` to redis service, because default is `network_mode: bridge` if you don't put anything